# Issue with the tabmeans.survey multi-categorical variables. Not recognising variables in the design

Tags: r, survey

I have had an issue with analysing survey data on r using the survey and tab packages.

I think I am setting up the survey design object correctly, but when i try to run the tabmean.survey function comparing the means across more than 2 categories, the function does not recognise the variable in the design.

Here's the example using my data:

```
svyd<-svydesign(id=~psu,                      #PSU variable
                  strata=~strata,             #Strata variable              
                  weights=~ca_betaindin_xw,   #Weight variable
                  data=usds)

svyd_emp<-subset(svyd, usds$samp_employ==1)   #subset the data to required analytic sample

t1<-tabmeans.svy(age~ethnicity, 
                 design = svyd_emp)           #Run tabmeans.svy comparing means of age by ethnicity
```

Which produces this error:

> Error in svyglm.survey.design(Age ~ 1, design = design) : 
>     all variables must be in design= argument

When I try the same function with a binary variable the function works

```
t2<-tabmeans.svy(age~sex, 
                 design = svyd_emp)           #Run tabmeans.svy comparing means of age by sex
                                              #WORKS
```

Comparing means across multi categorical variables using this function has previously worked. I can't figure out why the function is throwing up an error now. The survey.design object had the variables listed in the object.

I cannot share my data but I have reproduced the same issue using the 'api' dataset in the survey package.

```
data(api)
sdesign<-svydesign(id=~dnum+snum, 
                   strata=~stype, 
                   weights=~pw, 
                   data=apistrat, 
                   nest = TRUE)
t3<-tabmeans.svy(api00~stype,            # stype has 3 categories = DOESNT WORK
                    design=sdesign)
t4<-tabmeans.svy(api00~sch.wide,
                    design=sdesign)      # sch.wide has 2 categories = WORKS
```

Appreciate any thoughts or suggestions on how to get around this issue.

Many thanks

Comment: this function in the `library(tab)` looks like it has a mistake, you might want to file an issue on github?  if your variable has more than two levels, `tabmeans.svy` expects variables named `Age` and `Sex` despite not saying so in its documentation?  https://github.com/vandomed/tab/blob/master/R/tabmeans_svy.R#L179

Comment: The error message  `svyglm.survey.design(Age ~ 1, design = design)` says you used `Age` not `age`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reproducible example.  When I run it, I get

```
> t3<-tabmeans.svy(api00~stype,            # stype has 3 categories = DOESNT WORK
+                     design=sdesign)
Error in svyglm.survey.design(Age ~ 1, design = design) : 
  all variables must be in design= argument
> traceback()
4: stop("all variables must be in design= argument")
3: svyglm.survey.design(Age ~ 1, design = design)
2: svyglm(Age ~ 1, design = design)
1: tabmeans.svy(api00 ~ stype, design = sdesign)
```

which is disconcerting, because why is it trying to find an `Age` variable? (This was masked a little in your example, because you have an `age` variable).

Looking at the code for `tabmeans.svy` I see

```
    if (num.groups == 2) {
        fit <- svyttest(formula, design = design)
        diffmeans <- -fit$estimate
        diffmeans.ci <- -rev(as.numeric(fit$conf.int))
        p <- fit$p.value
    }
    else {
        fit1 <- svyglm(Age ~ 1, design = design)
        fit2 <- svyglm(Age ~ Sex, design = design)
        fit <- do.call(anova, c(list(object = fit1, object2 = fit2), 
            anova.svyglm.list))
        p <- as.numeric(fit$p)
    }
```

which explains the problem: if there are more than two groups it ignores your variables and instead tests for an effect of `Sex` on `Age`.

I suspect a cut-and-paste error by the maintainer. I have filed a GitHub issue. Unfortunately, I can't see a simple work-around.

Comment: Yes, that was the strange thing about the error message on the 'api' dataset.

Thanks for looking into this, although there's not an immediate solution, it makes me feel slightly comforted that the error wasn't because I had missed something obvious.